# Why is my route going to a wrong method that I specified nowhere (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, routes, request, controller

I have this weird issue where the following route: `admin.market-segments.orderProducts`

Is not going to `requestProductOrder` like I specified here in my route file:

```
Route::middleware('admin')
    ->name('market-segments.')
    ->namespace('App\Admin\Controllers')
    ->group(function () {
        Route::get('market-segments', 'MarketSegmentController@index')->name('index');
        Route::get('market-segments/data', 'MarketSegmentController@requestData')->name('data');
        Route::get('market-segments/create', 'MarketSegmentController@create')->name('create');
        Route::put('market-segments/order', 'MarketSegmentController@requestOrder')->name('order');
        Route::post('market-segments', 'MarketSegmentController@store')->name('store');
        Route::get('market-segments/{id}/edit', 'MarketSegmentController@edit')->name('edit');
        Route::put('market-segments/{id}', 'MarketSegmentController@update')->name('update');
        Route::delete('market-segments/{id}', 'MarketSegmentController@destroy')->name('destroy');

        Route::get('market-segments/productData/{id}', 'MarketSegmentController@requestProductData')->name('productData');
        Route::post('market-segments/updateProducts/{id}', 'MarketSegmentController@updateProducts')->name('updateProducts');
        Route::put('market-segments/orderProducts', 'MarketSegmentController@requestProductOrder')->name('orderProducts');
    });
```

The last route is what it should follow.

In my MarketSegmentController I have:

```
/**
 * Save order questions and groups
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @return type
 */
public function requestProductOrder(Request $request)
{
    dd($request);
    $data = json_decode($request->input('data'));

    foreach ($data as $i => $d) {
        $marketSegment = MarketSegment::withoutGlobalScope(ActiveScope::class)->find($d);
        $marketSegment->order = ($i + 1);

        $marketSegment->save();
    }

    return [
        'error' => false,
        'message' => 'Volgorde opgeslagen'
    ];
}
```

This uses an illuminate http request to just get some data, no validation anywhere, but in my console I get:

```
errors
: 
{name: ["naam is required."], seo_title: ["seo title is required."]}
message
: 
"The given data was invalid."
```

Which is strange so I figured it does not end up in that method, one by one I removed my methods to see where it ends up, and I see it ends up in my 'update' method.

Which looks like this:

```
/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(MarketSegmentRequest $request, $id)
{
    $marketSegment = MarketSegment::withoutGlobalScope(ActiveScope::class)->find($id);
    if (is_null($marketSegment)) {
        \Flash::error('Product niet gevonden');
        return redirect(route('admin.market-segments.index'));
    }

    $marketSegment->fill($request->all());
    if($request->products == null){
        $marketSegment->products = null;
    }
    if($request->categories == null){
        $marketSegment->categories = null;
    }
    $marketSegment->language_id = language()->id;
    $marketSegment->featured = $request->input('featured', false);
    $marketSegment->slug = Str::slug($request->name);
    $marketSegment->save();

    $marketSegment->handleUploader($request, 'image');
    $marketSegment->handleUploader($request, 'document');

    \Flash::success('Het product <strong>' . $marketSegment->title . '</strong> is opgeslagen.');

    if ($request->type_submit == "save_return") {
        return redirect()->route('admin.market-segments.index');
    }

    return redirect()->route('admin.market-segments.edit', ['id' => $id]);
}
```

This does have it's own request including validation. Why does it end up there? I never specify that route should go to the 'update' method.

Is this some laravel magic that I don't know about?

Comment: Your route should be `market-segments.orderProducts` according to the code snippet you shared.

Answer (score 0):

So this may be a simple route cache issue, but before we get into that please use route prefixes or resources.

```
Route::middleware('admin')
->name('market-segments.')
->prefix('market-segments')
->namespace('App\Admin\Controllers')
->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'MarketSegmentController@index')->name('index');
    Route::get('/data', 'MarketSegmentController@requestData')->name('data');
    Route::get('/create', 'MarketSegmentController@create')->name('create');
    Route::put('/order', 'MarketSegmentController@requestOrder')->name('order');
    Route::post('/', 'MarketSegmentController@store')->name('store');
    Route::get('/{id}/edit', 'MarketSegmentController@edit')->name('edit');
    Route::put('/{id}', 'MarketSegmentController@update')->name('update');
    Route::delete('/{id}', 'MarketSegmentController@destroy')->name('destroy');

    Route::get('/productData/{id}', 'MarketSegmentController@requestProductData')->name('productData');
    Route::post('/updateProducts/{id}', 'MarketSegmentController@updateProducts')->name('updateProducts');
    Route::put('/orderProducts', 'MarketSegmentController@requestProductOrder')->name('orderProducts');
});
```

Now that the routes look less heart attack inducing you should just run

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
```

If you are building a large application with many routes, you should make sure that you are running the route:cache Artisan command during your deployment process:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

And if that didnt fix anything look into your frontend that you did actually provide the right route name for the form!